# My code is really slow in IE8. But in Safari,firefox,chrome it works great

Tags: javascript, jquery

iam stuck now, i really hope if somebody can tell me the problems what i really don't see.

The problem is is the menubar works great in Safari,FF,Chrome. But when i open IE8 its so slow when i put my mouse cursor on another menu area. Or better the entire menu is just so slow!

**html id & class are**

```
  <div class="oe_wrapper">
     <ul id="oe_menu" class="oe_menu">
```

**this is my javascript code:**

```
$(function () {
    var $oe_menu = $('#oe_menu');
    var $oe_menu_items = $oe_menu.children('li');
    var $oe_overlay = $('#oe_overlay');

    $oe_menu_items.bind('mouseenter', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.addClass('slided selected');
        $this.children('div').css('z-index', '9999').stop(true, true).slideDown(300, function () {
            $oe_menu_items.not('.slided').children('div').hide();
            $this.removeClass('slided');
        });
    }).bind('mouseleave', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.removeClass('selected').children('div').css('z-index', '1');
    });

    $oe_menu.bind('mouseenter', function () {
        var $this = $(this);

        $this.addClass('hovered');
    }).bind('mouseleave', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.removeClass('hovered');

        $oe_menu_items.children('div').hide();
    })
});
```

this is my menu code:

```
<div class="oe_wrapper">


    <ul id="oe_menu" class="oe_menu">

        <li><a href="#">Lipsum</a>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li class="oe_heading">Lipsum</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li class="oe_heading">Lipsum</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lipsum</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lipsum</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lipsum</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>


        <li><a href="#">PRODUCTEN</a>
            <div style="left:-191px;">
                <ul>
                    <li class="oe_heading">Lipsum</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lipsum</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lipsum</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lipsum</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Persen</a></li>
                </ul>


                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Lipsum</a>
            <div style="left:-383px;">
                <ul class="oe_full">
                    <li class="oe_heading">Lipsum</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lipsum</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>


        <li><a href="#">Lipsum</a>
            <div style="left:-575px;">
                <ul>
                    <li class="oe_heading">Lipsum</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lipsum</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li class="oe_heading">Lipsum</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lipsum</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Lipsum</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>



        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a>
            <div style="left:-767px;">
                    <ul>
                    <li class="oe_heading">Lipsum/li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Lipsum</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lipsum</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

Comment: Re-tagging this to jQuery might get you more exposure.

Comment: From my experience, IE (I had issues with 8 specifically) has a harder time coping with Events - in comparison to the other browsers. It turns very sluggish when you try attaching too many events. How many menu items do you have? And I forgot to mention... IE is cr*p (pardon my language)

Comment: My menu is just normal in my eyes. Not that big or strange text.

Comment: Isn't that by design? I always though IE was built to annoy developers, so... =))

Comment: bamic01, please stop using answers as a place for comments. [Read the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) (all of it).

Comment: i really hate IE, but the users for the company are most IE users. And for the first time iam stuck with it

Comment: easy-way out: ask them to install [chromeframe](http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/) and add the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">` meta tag to your pages.

Comment: hahaha, is there no otherway that the menu get smooth?

Comment: But david, that not the right solution ;) i really wanna shoot IE but that not the right way. Because 80% of the traffic from my client is IE user.

Answer (score 1):

The performance drain is probably in the dom-traversal-on-event. Ie8 is notoriously slow at traversing the dom.

One way around this is to pre-traverse and cache the results like this:

```
$(function () {
    var $oe_menu = $('#oe_menu');
    var $oe_menu_items = $oe_menu.children('li');
    var $oe_overlay = $('#oe_overlay');

    $oe_menu_items.each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.data('div-children', $this.children('div'));                  
    });

    $oe_menu_items.bind('mouseenter', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.addClass('slided selected');
        $this.data('div-children').css('z-index', '9999').stop(true, true).slideDown(300, function () {
            $oe_menu_items.not('.slided').data('div-children').hide();
            $this.removeClass('slided');
        });
    }).bind('mouseleave', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.removeClass('selected').data('div-children').css('z-index', '1');
    });

    $oe_menu.bind('mouseenter', function () {
        var $this = $(this);

        $this.addClass('hovered');
    }).bind('mouseleave', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.removeClass('hovered');

        $oe_menu_items.children('div').hide();
    })
});
```

Comment: No 1.4.3 should be fine, tho upgrading probably won't hurt :)

Comment: Hi Martin, i updated the .js file now. But it's still slow check the link i posted http://www.cyko.nl/test/overons.html

Comment: jQuery 1.5 will be out soon. You might as well wait for that.

Comment: Martin did you saw the link that i posted? What do you think why it's that slow? maybe wrong css codes? or is it the js?

Comment: I took a look at your site, and ran it through dynatrace - it seems your problem is rendering and not js - as far as i can tell ie8 simply cannot render your markup fast enough to make it run smoothly.

Comment: So it's better to write another code? or is it my css/html that bugs the place?

Comment: The solution is probably to make your markup simpler, so it is easier for ie8 to render while it animates it.

Comment: mm the jquery code you mean? or my css? i really wanna thank you Martin for the great support.

Comment: I am talking about the actual markup on your page (the html tags), but also the css - think of it like this: the more tags and css rules, the heavier the page. The browser needs to figure out the styling rules for all the tags and how they affect each other when it "paints" the page. Now throw in the animation where it needs to do all these calculations again and again, and you can see why the browser might be struggling. Different browsers have different strength and weaknesses on this point, and you have probably been unlucky enough to hit one of ie8s many many weaknesses.

Comment: thx Martin, i think that i gonna serperate some css area's like menu, and each content box, but is the javascript jquery code correct now for ie8 that you gave me? Or do i need too change that in a different way to get the same result?

Comment: I don't think i am able to get any closer to a correct solution without actually working with the code - it's trial and error from here for you... the problem you need to solve is not slow javascript but slow render time - play around with the markup and css until you hit a solution that ie8 likes to render in an animation. If you use a lot of floats for instance, try to position the elements instead - go for simplicity, think of it from a browsers point of view - whats easiest to calculate

Answer (score 0):

Try using [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

Comment: still have no clue, iam not that skilled. My teacher told me this website because of the great support.